# AWS IoT TwinMaker with AWS Managed Grafana Annotation Problem - Unknown component type DataOverlay

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-sitewise

I am working with AWS IoT Twinmaker and AWS Managed Grafana in eu-west-2 (Ireland) region. I am building out a WindFarm scene and I am attempting to add a data bound annotation. This seems to work fine within AWS IoT Twinmaker console.

[image: Data binding]

But when I load in AWS Managed Grafana I get the following error:

> Unknown component type DataOverlay.

[image: Unknown component type]

I have also configured an overlay on a tag:

[image: Tag overlay]

And I get the same error (albeit duplicated because I have both the tag and the annotation)

[image: Overlay error]

Has anyone got this working? Am I doing something obviously wrong or does this just not work!

Comment: I'll suggest to post your question in https://repost.aws/